# How to make point unit align in css?

Tags: css

How do I make a css like the image below. If there is an easy way, happy to change div structure.

[image]

I tried

```
<div className='row paragraph paragraph-paragraph-margin'>
                    <div className='col xs-12 beCenter'>
                        <div className='pointHistoryBigPoint'>
                            <span className='pointHistoryBigPointNum'>5,651</span>
                            <span className='pointHistoryBigPointUnit'>PTS</span>
                            <span className='pointHistoryBigPointStar'>*</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

css

```
  .pointHistoryBigPoint {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova";

    /*
    width: 200px;
    height: 52px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    */
    height: 100px;
  }

  .pointHistoryBigPointNum {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Semi Bold";
    /*font-size: 60px;*/
  }

  .pointHistoryBigPointUnit {
    /*font-size:20px;*/
  }

  .pointHistoryBigPointStar {

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `display: flex` to your container so now each span takes the container height, and also set `line-height` to be equal to the font size, which will make you text stick to the top.

```css
.pointHistoryBigPoint {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova";
  width: 200px;
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.pointHistoryBigPointNum {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semi Bold";
  font-size: 60px;
}

.pointHistoryBigPointUnit {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.pointHistoryBigPointStar {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div className='row paragraph paragraph-paragraph-margin'>
  <div class='col xs-12 beCenter'>
    <div class='pointHistoryBigPoint'>
      <span class='pointHistoryBigPointNum'>5,651</span>
      <span class='pointHistoryBigPointUnit'>PTS</span>
      <span class='pointHistoryBigPointStar'>*</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) tag

```html
<div className='row paragraph paragraph-paragraph-margin'>
                    <div className='col xs-12 beCenter'>
                        <div className='pointHistoryBigPoint'>
                            <span className='pointHistoryBigPointNum'>5,651</span>
                            <sup className='pointHistoryBigPointUnit'>PTS*</sup>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```